# Overriding a theme redux file in child theme

Tags: php, functions, customization, child-theme

I am using a theme which uses the Redux framework for customisation options. I have created a child theme to customise this theme. In the theme framework I want to edit one of the files. To do this I thought I could just copy the file to my child theme and it would override but it seems not. A bit of research says I can use a filter in my functions file to do this but I'm not sure how to go about it.

The section of code I want to edit looks like this and is in my customizer.php file

```
    $this->sections[] = array(
  'title' => esc_html__('Footer', 'maverick-theme'),
  'desc' => esc_html__('Configure footer styles.', 'maverick-theme'),
  'subsection' => true,
  'fields' => array(
    array(
      'id'        => 'customizer-footer-bg-color',
      'type'      => 'color',
      'title'     => esc_html__('Background Color', 'maverick-theme'),
      'default'   => '',
      'output'    => array('background-color' => '#main-footer, #bottom-footer')
    ),
    array(
      'id'        => 'customizer-footer-social-color',
      'type'      => 'color',
      'title'     => esc_html__('Social Icon Color', 'maverick-theme'),
      'default'   => '',
      'output'    => array('color' => '#bottom-footer .social-icons li a')
    ),
    array(
      'id'        => 'customizer-footer-social-hover-color',
      'type'      => 'color',
      'title'     => esc_html__('Social Icon Hover Color', 'maverick-theme'),
      'default'   => '',
      'output'    => array('color' => '#bottom-footer .social-icons li a:hover i'),
      'important' => true
    ),
  ),
);
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you need to add the settings in parent theme created section, just place the below code in child functions.php

But remember to replace OPT Name with *your_opt_name* in "OPT_NAME".(To find OPT Name just open /parent-theme/includes/options/options-config.php and in top there's a line $opt_name = '*your_opt_name*'; )

```
    function add_product_description($sections){

    $sections[10]['fields'][] = array(
                'id'        => 'product_extra_description',
                'type'      => 'multi_text',
                'title'     => __( 'Product Description', 'nm-framework-admin' ),
                'desc'      => __( 'Enter extra Product Description.', 'nm-framework-admin' ),
                'validate'  => 'html'
    );

    return $sections;
}
// In this example OPT_NAME is the returned opt_name.
//add_filter("redux/options/OPT_NAME/sections", 'add_another_section_bl');
add_filter("redux/options/OPT_NAME/sections", 'add_product_description');
```

Also in $sections[10], you need to replace with your indexing. And to find it you need to print_r the $section.